# Connecting using SnowSQL denied 403 error

Tags: connection, database-connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to configure JDBC but kept getting the same error I am getting using snowsql:

```
250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: JG3409.canada-central.azure.snowflakecomputing.com:443. 000403: 403: HTTP 403: Forbidden
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

I have configured the config file, and I have double checked the account, company, region, reset password to only use alphanumeric.

I have used both forms of the URL

The only possibility is that I am using a trial account, but I can't imagine that this would limit external non-browser connections?

I use a simple user/password, I have whitelisted my IP and I don't have a problem with a proxy or a firewall.  I can successfully connect using a browser.. using:

https://app.snowflake.com/canada-central.azure/jg63409

Important contents of the config file:

```
[connections]
accountname=JG3409
#accountname=uegxydq-pz20606
region=canada-central.azure
username=ASHSNOWFLAKE
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the OS that you are using SNowSQL, can you try running from the prompt and see if it works . $ snowsql -a <account_identifier> -u <user_name>

Answer (score 2):

Your account is not JG3409 but JG63409 based on this link:

https://app.snowflake.com/canada-central.azure/jg63409

Try in your browser:

https://jg63409.canada-central.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: You are indeed correct! and TY! 
.. however .. see my answer below ... it wasn't my only problem!

Answer (score 1):

I found out using snowcd that my computer could not connect via my home router.
When I used my personal hotspot on my (5G) phone, snowcd passed all the tests immediately.  The problem then arose how to adjust the network security policy to allow a CIDR block of network addresses through since my phone uses a new address every time I connect, and I can't edit the policy to allow my phone while connected via my phone (for obvious reasons)

Catch 22

123.45.0.0/16 is not accepted in the new Snowflake UI, and 0.0.0.0 doesn't work for me, but the documentation gave me a clue.. the new UI doesn't separate by commas, so I switched to the old UI and voila!

Incidentally the OLD UI uses the same URL as SnowSQL so I picked up my error in my account number there as well (although I should have seen it earlier).

Diabolical but thanks @Sergiu too!